# Having trouble with initWithTimeInterval

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I'm new to ios programming.

I'm trying to get the date of death by the code below.
But, I get the unexpected result.

In the example code below, someone's birthdate is 1899-12-31 and this person's death age is 80.

So, I'm expecting this person's deathdate is 1979-12-31.
But, the result I get is 1843-11-05 08:31:44 +0000.

Could anyone please tell me what's wrong with this code?

Thanks!!

```
NSInteger year = [_selectedDeathAge intValue];
NSLog(@"%d", year); //80

NSLog(@"%@", _selectedBirthDate);//(NSDate)1899-12-31 15:00:00 +0000 

NSDate *deathDate = [_selectedBirthDate initWithTimeInterval:year * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 sinceDate:_selectedBirthDate];

NSLog(@"%@", deathDate);//(NSDate)1843-11-05 08:31:44 +0000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `NSDate` to do relative date computations. Use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *yearsComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
yearsComponents.year = [_selectedDeathAge intValue];
NSDate *deathDate = [cal dateByAddingComponents:yearsComponents toDate:_selectedBirthDate];
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works!! I'm accepting your answer in 4 mins.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be calling the `initWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:` method on another instance.

You should be doing this instead:

```
NSDate *deathDate = [_selectedBirthDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:year * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60];
```

Or you can do it this way:

```
NSDate *deathDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithWithTimeInterval:year * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 sinceDate:_selectedBirthDate];
```

But in the end, you should use the solution from "Jacob Relkin". It's the better solution for this type of calculation.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Oh that's true. _selectedBirthDate is an initilized object. I shouldn't call initilize method on this. I voted your answer! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

`NSDate *deathDate = [_selectedBirthDate initWithTimeInterval:year * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 sinceDate:_selectedBirthDate];`

This line is wrong, and you should expect strange results.  You are calling init on an already initialized function.  You need to create it via `[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:]` and furthermore, you should not hardcode the time interval like that.  Look up `NSDateComponents`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm going to look up NSDateComponents.